# How to target a model and access records nested two levels deep in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

I am trying to create a todo list application in ruby on rails that has 3 models as nested resources.

For Example:

- User: `has_many :todo_lists`
- TodoList: `has_many :todo_items` & `belongs_to :user`
- TodoItem: `belongs_to :todo_list` & `scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }`

Running `@user.todo_lists` returns the user's todo lists.

Running `@todo_lists.todo_items` returns the todo list's todo items.

Running `@todo_lists.todo_items.completed` returns the todo list's completed todo items.

But

Running `@user.todo_lists.todo_items` returns error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'todo_items'`.

Running `@user.todo_lists.todo_items.completed` also returns error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'todo_items'`.

We have tried `@user.todo_lists.map(&:todo_items).flatten` which returns all the todo items for a user but we cannot add the `.completed` scope.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this @Deepak & @slehmann36?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using has_many :through association.

In your user model define association:

```
has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists
```

You should than be able to get todo_items without getting todo_lists first.

```
user.todo_items.completed
```

Using the map you were on the right track.

```
user.todo_lists.map { |todo_list| todo_list.todo_items.completed }.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these errors

1-

```
@user.todo_lists.todo_items

NoMethodError: undefined method 'todo_items'.
```

Try with

```
@user.todo_lists
```

This will return you active record array or nil but if if you will get nil so you you will error undefined method 'todo_items'. for nil class

Now you are getting result in array so you can not use this method so you can go with the below command

```
@user.todo_lists.map{|m| {todo_lists: m, todo_items: m.todo_items}}
```

This will return you todo_lists in array and in first record of todo_lists you will get todo_items of that todo_list.
if you want to get only todo items use below command

```
@user.todo_lists.map{|m| m.todo_items}
```

2-

```
@user.todo_lists.map(&:todo_items).flatten.completed
```

use command

```
@user.todo_lists.map(&:todo_items).flatten.collect(&:completed)
```